# Check if a list contains at least one variable non null

Tags: kotlin

I'm making my first app in Kotlin and there is a lot of syntax I don't know, and I was wondering if there is a better way to check if a list contains at least one non null entry.

For now my solution is:

```
var atLeastOneValue: Boolean
var i = 0

for (x in list) {
    if (x != null) atLeastOneValue = true
    else i++
}
if (list.size == i) atLeastOneValue = false

return atLeastOneValue
```

I'm working with `MutableList<String>`.

Comment: `list.any { it == null }`. https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html

Comment: Note that a MutableList<String>, by definition of the type String which is a non-nullable type, can't possibly contain null. If it was a MutableList<String?>, then it could. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Comment: Yes you right it was with MutableList<String?>. Thank you very much for the fast answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/contains.html) function for that:

```
val hasNull = list.contains(null)
```

`contains` can also be called in the operator form, it corresponds to the [operator `in`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#in):

```
val hasNull = null in list
val hasNoNull = null !in list
```

Comment: What if the list is empty?

Comment: @gidds It clearly doesn't contain null in this case.

Comment: Yes, but the question wasn't whether the list contains any nulls; it was whether it contains any _non_-nulls, which would only be true if the list were non-empty _and_ had no nulls.

Comment: Oh, in that case the condition `list.isNotEmpty()` could be checked in addition to `null !in list`.

Comment: Indeed.  Would that not be better edited into your answer (with an explanation)?  — This illustrates that a good developer must _always_ be asking “What if…?” and “How could this go wrong?”